# How to get this pattern in iOS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

I am wondering where I can get this pattern in Xcode?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for actually having an image!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have it with:

```
[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]
```